# How to find a DataFrame column with only whitespace

Tags: pyspark

How can I replace a string which contains only whitespace with None?

Example strings:

### Input:

```
"   ",       
" Hello There ",      
"Hi World"
```

### Output:

```
null,    
" Hello There ",       
"Hi World"
```

I have used below line but replace everything with null.

```
df=df.withColumn('TITLE_LINE_3',F.regexp_replace(F.trim(df.TITLE_LINE_3),"^\s+$",None))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a an `udf` to strip the whitespaces from your `column` and further identify using a `when-otherwise` , if they are empty and replace them with `None`

#### Data Preparation

```
sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(
        [
          ("   ",),
          (" Hi There ",),
          ("Hello World",),
        ],
        ("text",)
    )

sparkDF.show()

+-----------+
|       text|
+-----------+
|           |
|  Hi There |
|Hello World|
+-----------+
```

#### Strip UDF

```
strip_udf = F.udf(lambda x:x.strip(),StringType())

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('preprocessed_text',strip_udf(F.col('text')))    


sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('preprocessed_text',F.when(F.col('preprocessed_text') == '',None)\
                             .otherwise(F.col('preprocessed_text'))\
                        )

sparkDF.show()

+-----------+-----------------+
|       text|preprocessed_text|
+-----------+-----------------+
|           |             null|
|  Hi There |         Hi There|
|Hello World|      Hello World|
+-----------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `trim` the column and check if it's empty to replace it with `null`.

```
df.withColumn('TITLE_LINE_3', when(trim('TITLE_LINE_3') == '', None).otherwise(col('TITLE_LINE_3')))
```